# Repetir campos de acordo com o numero do dropdown

Tags: javascript, html

Como Não sei muito de javascript gostaria de uma ajuda de como fazer que ao escolher um numero no dropdown, repeti-se os campos pelo valo escolhido

```
<select id="valores5" class="valores1 form-control" name="npax">

<option value="0">1</option>
<option value="1">2</option>
<option value="2">3</option>
<option value="3">4</option>
<option value="4">5</option>
<option value="5">6</option>
<option value="6">7</option>
<option value="7">8</option>
<option value="8">9</option>
 </select> 

//loop   x quantidade do select
<div>
<input class="form-control" value="" type="text" name="nome">
<input class="form-control" value="" type="text" name="cpf">
<input class="form-control" value="" type="text" name="tel"> 
<div>
//fim loop
```

Comment: acho que entendi errado, vc quer que repita esse conjunto (3) de inputs tantas vezes quanto for o valor do option?

Comment: exato ... repetir o conjunto

Comment: editei a resposta

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o Jquery e criar de acordo com os ids e classes.

Segue um exemplo para você poder fazer uns testes conforme suas necessidades.

```js
$('#valores5').change(function() {
  let valores5 = $('#valores5').val()
  
  $('.div-campo-controle').remove();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < valores5; i++) {
    let novosCampos = $("#campo-modelo").clone()
    novosCampos.attr('id', 'campo='.concat(i + 1));
    novosCampos.addClass('div-campo-controle')
    novosCampos.insertAfter("div.div-campo:last");
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="valores5" class="valores1 form-control" name="npax">

<option value="0">1</option>
<option value="1">2</option>
<option value="2">3</option>
<option value="3">4</option>
<option value="4">5</option>
<option value="5">6</option>
<option value="6">7</option>
<option value="7">8</option>
<option value="8">9</option>
 </select> 

<div id="campos">
<div id="campo-modelo" class="div-campo" >
<input class="form-control" value="" type="text" name="nome">
<input class="form-control" value="" type="text" name="cpf">
<input class="form-control" value="" type="text" name="tel"> 
<div>
<div>
```

Comment: Show... é isso mesmo só que não esta removendo se diminuirmos os numeros

Comment: Só trabalhar a lógica. Você pode apagar os campos usando o método remove() no jquery. https://api.jquery.com/remove/

Comment: ola amigo não consegui fazer funcionar o remove()

Comment: e ele esta somando os campos, se escolher 2  e depois trocar pra 3 ele mostra 5 linhas

Comment: @FabioHenrique Atualizei o código conforme vc precisa. Eu adicionei uma classe às divs na iteração e eu removo todas as divs conforme essa classe antes de recriá-las

Answer (score 1):

**Javascript puro**

onchange - o evento ocorre quando o valor de um elemento for alterado

```js
function criarInputs() {

//recupera o valor do option selecionado (n)
let select = document.getElementById('valores5');
let n = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
let campos=""

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    
   //só pra ver no console.log
   console.log('<input class="form-control" value="" type="text" name="nome"><input class="form-control" value="" type="text" name="cpf"><input class="form-control" value="" type="text" name="tel">');

  } 

}
```

```html
<select id="valores5" class="valores1 form-control" name="npax" onchange="criarInputs()">

    <option value="0">1</option>
    <option value="1">2</option>
    <option value="2">3</option>
    <option value="3">4</option>
    <option value="4">5</option>
    <option value="5">6</option>
    <option value="6">7</option>
    <option value="7">8</option>
    <option value="8">9</option>

</select>
```

---

---

Observe que nos inputs o atributo `“name”` tem o mesmo valor para cada conjunto novo adicionado.

Para simplificar imagine o seguinte formulário:

```
    <form id='form' action="teste.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="nome" value='nome1'>
        <input type="text" name="nome" value='nome2'>
        <button type="submit"> Enviar </button>
    </form>
```

Após fazer a requisição, no teste.php eu exibo as informações que vieram do form e o retorno é esse:

```
Array ( [nome] => nome2 ) 1
```

Veja que apesar de eu ter dois input’s no formulário, só foi me enviado um. Isso acontece porque quando um form é submetido e este tem vários input’s com o valor do atributo `“name”` iguais, só o último é considerado.

**Para resolver isso**

Para que todos input’s com o mesmo valor do atributo `“name”` sejam entregues após requisição, basta adicionar colchetes ao lado do valor do atributo `“name”`. Exemplo:

```
    <input type="text" name="nome[]" value='nome1'>
    <input type="text" name="nome[]" value='nome2'>
```

---

---

**Seu código teria que ser**

```js
    function criarInputs() {

      //recupera o valor do option selecionado (n)
    let select = document.getElementById('valores5');
    let n = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    let campos="";

      for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
           if (n>1){
            console.log('<input class="form-control" value="" type="text" name="nome[]"><input class="form-control" value="" type="text" name="cpf[]"><input class="form-control" value="" type="text" name="tel[]">');
          }else{
            console.log('<input class="form-control" value="" type="text" name="nome"><input class="form-control" value="" type="text" name="cpf"><input class="form-control" value="" type="text" name="tel">');
          }
            
      } 
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = campos;

    }
```

```html
    <select id="valores5" class="valores1 form-control" name="npax" onchange="criarInputs()">

        <option value="0">1</option>
        <option value="1">2</option>
        <option value="2">3</option>
        <option value="3">4</option>
        <option value="4">5</option>
        <option value="5">6</option>
        <option value="6">7</option>
        <option value="7">8</option>
        <option value="8">9</option>
     </select>
     
     <div id="demo"></div>
```

**Para não haver a duvida quanto ao comentário** `"Quase isso.... só que se eu escolher o numero 4 e depois trocar um menor tipo o 2 ele esta somando 4 mais 2 ao invés de remover"`

**Vamos executar sem console.log**

```js
    function criarInputs() {

      //recupera o valor do option selecionado (n)
    let select = document.getElementById('valores5');
    let n = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    let campos="";

      for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {

          if (n>1){
             campos +='<input class="form-control" value="" type="text" name="nome[]"><input class="form-control" value="" type="text" name="cpf[]"><input class="form-control" value="" type="text" name="tel[]"><br><br>';
          }else{
             campos +='<input class="form-control" value="" type="text" name="nome"><input class="form-control" value="" type="text" name="cpf"><input class="form-control" value="" type="text" name="tel"><br><br>';
          }   
        
      } 
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = campos;

    }
```

```html
    <select id="valores5" class="valores1 form-control" name="npax" onchange="criarInputs()">

        <option value="0">1</option>
        <option value="1">2</option>
        <option value="2">3</option>
        <option value="3">4</option>
        <option value="4">5</option>
        <option value="5">6</option>
        <option value="6">7</option>
        <option value="7">8</option>
        <option value="8">9</option>
     </select>
     
     <div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Quase isso.... só que se eu escolher o numero 4   e depois trocar um menor tipo o 2 ele esta somando 4 mais 2 ao invés de remover

Comment: @FabioHenrique da uma olhada na função createFields da minha resposta, usa aquela lógica lá pra 'zerar' os inputs antes de inserir eles

Comment: Não está somando não, é que console.log não apaga

Comment: Vc pode ver pela data no console.log, cada seleção é uma hora diferente

Comment: @FabioHenrique, aqui não vejo erro. Qual seria?

Comment: Pode ter sido antes da edição que colei código errado

Comment: sim foi isso mesmo

Answer (score 0):

Bom, tu pode gerar esse html por meio do JS, da pra fazer assim:

Arrumei teus values no select, não tem pq começar do 0 se você vai iterar pra gerar os inputs

```
<select id="valores5" class="valores1 form-control" onchange='createFields()' name="npax">

<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
 </select> 
 
 <div id='exemplo'>
 
 </div>
```

Fazer uma div pra ser o "wrapper" dos teus inputs e gerar eles dinâmicamente. Aqui vai o script pra tu usar, daria pra economizar umas linhas nesse código mas deixei assim pra ficar um pouco mais fácil de entender

```
let parent = document.getElementById('exemplo')

function createDiv () {
  let div_html = document.createElement('div'); // criar uma div pra botar os 3 campos
  //criar os campos com os atributos que você quer
  let input1 = document.createElement('input');
  input1.type = 'text';
  input1.name = 'nome';
  input1.class = 'form-control';
  let input2 = document.createElement('input');
  input2.type = 'text';
  input2.name = 'cpf';
  input2.class = 'form-control';
  let input3 = document.createElement('input');
  input3.type = 'text';
  input3.name = 'tel';
  input3.class = 'form-control';
  // montar a div com os 3 fields
  div_html.appendChild(input1)
  div_html.appendChild(input2)
  div_html.appendChild(input3)
  
  return div_html
}

function createFields() {
  // remover os campos que já estão dentro do parent, pra não ficar adicionando campos um atrás do outro
  while(parent.firstChild) {
    parent.removeChild(parent.firstChild);
}
  let num = document.getElementById('valores5').value // pegar valor do select
  for (let x = 0; x < Number(num); x++) {
   parent.appendChild(createDiv()) // adicionar a div com os fields, iterando o valor do select
  }
 
}
```